# Django File Upload Run a function on a file and store in a database?

Tags: python, django

So I am uploading files into my database in django. To do this I am using [django-database-files](https://github.com/bfirsh/django-database-files). What I want to do though is to run a function on the uploaded file so I won't have to read the file every time and so I can query some information. I want one table with just the stored files (so this doesn't have to be queried often) and another table that is populated by reading and parsing the file. Here is a basic overview of how I have my models setup:

```
class Report(models.Model):
    #Machine Run File
    report = models.FileField(upload_to='not required')

class Report_Info(models.Model):
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    ... I have more fields that are calculated from the file
    file = ForeignKey(Report)
```

I am wondering how I can upload the file and also populate the Report_Info model based on the file that was uploaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest is overriding `Report.save`:

```
class Report(models.Model):
    report = ...

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        super(Report, self).save(**kwargs)
        try:
            # 'Report_Info' is just the ugliest name possible
            report_info = ReportInfo.objects.get(file=self)
        except ReportInfo.DoesNotExist:
            report_info = ReportInfo(file=self)
        # process self.report and fill report_info fields
        report_info.save()
```